# Can I say kiddush levana during daylight hours if the moon is visible?

Tags: kiddush-levanah, zemanim, moon

Suppose it's late afternoon or early morning and the moon is visible -- can I say it then?  Or must it be at "night"?  (If so, how do we define "night"?)

Comment: If the moon is visible in the early morning then you cannot say Kiddush Levana. That would be in the second half of the month!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Rema 426:1 says it must be night when "the moon is shining and (people) benefit from its light".  The Mishna Berurah exludes bein hashemashos and equates benefiting from its light with the time that the moonshine is detectable on the land.

Comment: In other words, after Tzeis

Comment: Yes, but since it's not dependent on tzais, rather on practical benefit, you needn't hem and haw about the shittos of tzais.  Rather it depends on the metzius- is the contrast enough to give benefit.

Comment: YDK, give it 100 years, and if enough people ask about it, this will be tied to a specific "objective" shiur too.

Comment: Isaac, at the current rate of increase in decay of the mesora of halachic principles, it will be much sooner than 100 years!

Comment: A diyuk in the Rema that you have to have benefit from the light would start monthly pilgrimages to the mountains!

Comment: @YDK The *Machatzis HaShekel* ad loc. indicates that the time when the moon is shining brightly probably equates exactly to after *tzeis* (when three medium stars are visible).

Comment: @Fred That seems unlikely as [the Rama later](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%91_%D7%90) says that three medium stars is the equivalent of "the moon shining with strength" not just when it's merely "shining".

Comment: @DoubleAA That's actually exactly what the [*Machatzis HaShekel*](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2141) proposes; he equates the Rama's "shining with strength" in 562:1 with the Rama's "shining and people can benefit from its light." But he does mention that this is just a possibility and that those might be two separate times/events.

Comment: @Fred Considering the overwhelmingly dominant opinion that KL can be said on Rosh Chodesh, it's very hard to exclude Bein HaShemashot (unless you really think BhSh is only 13 minutes long). See too Yabia Omer OC 5:36 who permits saying KL after Alot Hashachar before Hanetz (the opposite BhSh).

Comment: @DoubleAA The Machatzis HaShekel's proposal might be similar to the שרגא בטיהרא מאי מהניא issue (according to those opinions who say not to light Chanuka candles until *tzeis*), where, so long as there is some significant light from the atmosphere perhaps additional light from the moon is moot. But even if the moon is very new, the blessing can be said once the sky is dark. Alternatively, per R' Moshe Feinstein's explanation of the Shulchan Aruch's opinion, the need to benefit from the light is only necessary if you are not saying the blessing near Rosh Chodesh.