# Can a person recite Kiddush Levana during the Polar summer months?

Tags: halacha, kiddush-levanah

[This M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2649/5275) states that the moonlight must be visible on the land for someone to be able to say *Kiddush Levana*.

During the summer season near either the North or South Poles, there is an area of the Earth where the sun never sets completely. It approaches the horizon, but there is probably still too much light for the moon's light to be noticeable on the land. Does this imply that someone who is there during these months could not say *Kiddush Levana* at all?

Comment: I recall some midrash brought down about Adam harishon being shown areas of human habitability on earth. It's interpreted to refer to the area between the arctic and antarctic circles, and was used in a discussion of Torah observance of time while in orbit. Also related: observing shabbos on an island with no calendar to keep track. Both of these refer to passage of time, an irrelevant factor for kiddush levanah, which requires specifically ***observation of the waxing moon*** and would therefore be impossible where the moon is never visible. Head toward the equator for a couple days a month!

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Even if you located a source, I'm not sure it would answer the question. There are halachot regarding davening times and Shabbat starting times for people residing in these areas despite the premise stated in the Midrash. *tzarich iyun yater*

Comment: That's the point; THOSE questions have an answer since you determine time using a reference point OUTSIDE the current location. Kiddush Levana isn't an issue of TIME, it's an issue of PERCEPTION, which you can't "fake" by acting as though you were in a different location. Otherwise, we could make brachos on paintings of a rainbow and would tear keriyah when we see a photo of the Kotel...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Your last comment is interesting, and might make an answer if you could further support it. I'm fine with an answer of "No" ;-)